# No route matches {:action=>“show”...} missing required keys: [:id] when accessing New Action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Why is happening this when I'm trying to access the action new?

[image]

**routes.rb**

```
resources :tvseries
```

**tvseries_controller.rb**

```
class TvseriesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_tvseries, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /tvseries
  # GET /tvseries.json
  def index
    @tvseries = Tvserie.all
  end

  # GET /tvseries/1
  # GET /tvseries/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /tvseries/new
  def new
    @tvseries = Tvserie.new
  end

  # GET /tvseries/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /tvseries
  # POST /tvseries.json
  def create
    @tvseries = Tvserie.new(tvseries_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @tvseries.save
        format.html { redirect_to @tvseries, notice: 'Tvserie was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @tvseries }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @tvseries.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /tvseries/1
  # PATCH/PUT /tvseries/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @tvseries.update(tvseries_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @tvseries, notice: 'Tvserie was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @tvseries }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @tvseries.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /tvseries/1
  # DELETE /tvseries/1.json
  def destroy
    @tvseries.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to tvseries_url, notice: 'Tvserie was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  # GET /all_tv_series
  def all
    @tv_series = Tvserie.all
  end

  # GET /tv_series/add_language/1
  # GET /tv_s/add_language/1.json
  def add_subtitles
    @languages = Language.all
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_tvseries
      @tvseries = Tvserie.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def tvseries_params
      params.require(:tvseries).permit(:title, :image, :description)
    end
end
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@tvseries) do |f| %>
  <% if @tvseries.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@tvseries.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this tvseries from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @tvseries.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :image %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :image %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**rake routes**

```
 tvseries_index GET    /tvseries(.:format)                 tvseries#index
                POST   /tvseries(.:format)                 tvseries#create
   new_tvseries GET    /tvseries/new(.:format)             tvseries#new
  edit_tvseries GET    /tvseries/:id/edit(.:format)        tvseries#edit
       tvseries GET    /tvseries/:id(.:format)             tvseries#show
                PATCH  /tvseries/:id(.:format)             tvseries#update
                PUT    /tvseries/:id(.:format)             tvseries#update
                DELETE /tvseries/:id(.:format)             tvseries#destroy
```

**schema**

```
  create_table "tvseries", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.string   "image"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end
```

Comment: Can you please show the **link_to** tag from which you are trying to open the **tvseries/new** path ?

Comment: It's `<%= link_to 'New TV Serie', new_tvseries_path %>`, but it's so strange, I've other models and controllers like movie or anime, and I can enter to movies/new or animes/new just by writing it on the browser or trough a link_to, but tvseries fail in both ways.

Comment: Can we see the whole `form_for`?

Comment: It looks **form_for @tvseries** is throwing the UrlGeneration error

Comment: I edited the post, the _form is there now

Comment: Very very strange... just for the sake of argument try `<%= form_for(@tvseries, method: :post) do |f| %>`

Comment: Can you please post the output for `rake routes`, but only the section that mentions `tvseries`?

Comment: Can you please post the schema for `tvseries` also? Perhaps you managed to drop the `id` column, or prevented it from being generated?

Comment: Tried `<%= form_for(@tvseries, method: :post) do |f| %>` but got the error too, I've added rake routes and schema, BTW, I used `rails g scaffold_controller tvserie` to create the controller and `rails g model controller tv_serie`, but I did the same for other models and controllers and didn't have this problem.

Comment: K, I got tired about these and just use rails g scaffold_controller tvshow and rails g model tvshow and worked fine, I'm gonna delete this question since I'm not gonna even try to solve this anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with naming convention.

Tvseries can be used for both singular and plural form.

You should change your model name to `Tvseries` instead of `Tvserie`